# Multiple spring project on server can exchange data between them

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two spring project deployed on same server, is there any way to access the
object of one application to other application

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options.  JMS is popular for pushing messages between Java applications.  You could also create a SOAP/REST web service API for client/server communication.

Both can be integrated with Spring.

- [Docs for Spring and JMS](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/jms.html)
- [Docs for Spring and REST](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html)

You could also do non-Spring related things like RMI, but I think it's easier to use what you already have.